# Mapping edges in $n$-cube grid to 1-dimensional indices

Tags: geometry

### Motivation

For an $n$-cube grid with size $D_1, D_2, ..., D_n$, there are $C = \prod_{i = 1}^n D_i$ $n$-cubes. One can assign a coordinate in the grid $(d_1, d_2, ..., d_n)$ to every $n$-cube. Then, one can assign a unique cube index $I_c$ (from $0$ to $C - 1$) to every $n$-cube via this formula:

$$I_c = \sum_{i = 1}^n d_i \prod_{j = 1}^{i - 1} D_j$$

For example, in 3D, if you have a $2 \times 6 \times 7$ grid of cubes, the cube at coordinate $(1, 5, 3)$ would have the index $1 + 5 \times 2 + 3 \times 2 \times 6 = 47$.

### Question

In an $n$-cube grid, the "edges" between the $n$-cubes are $(n-1)$-cubes (for example, lines in 2D or squares in 3D). There are $E = n \prod_{i = 1}^n D_i + \sum_{i = 1}^n D_i$ of these edges (here I am including the outer edges).

I can assign a coordinate to each of the edges by using their midpoint coordinate (assuming the $n$-cubes have side lengths 1). But the exact choice of coordinates for the edges is not *super* important here as long as it relates to where the edge is located in space somehow.

Can I in a similar fashion to the $n$-cubes map all these edges to unique edge indices $I_e$ from $0$ to $E - 1$?

I have found this formula which works in 2D, but I am not sure how it generalizes (I'm assuming it's possible to generalize it):

$$I_e = d_1 + d_2(2D_1 + 1) - 0.5$$

For example, in a $2 \times 2$ square grid, the edge in between $(0,0)$ and $(0,1)$ has the midpoint coordinate $(0.5,1)$ (I'm assuming the square with coordinate $(x, y)$ has its bottom-left corner at $(x, y)$). Hence it would have the index $0.5 + 1 \times (2 \times 2 + 1) - 0.5 = 5$. This makes sense, it fits with these indices of the edges (see image).

[a 2x2 square grid with indices for the edges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ak20Y.png)

How can I generalize this to 3D? And beyond?

Comment: I think my edge count formula ($E$) is wrong actually... but question still stands.